# mongo element match by date

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to find records in the mongodb before 2020-11-25T00:00:00.000Z

Each record has a `crawls` array where each crawl's date is stored.

Right now this query returns `[]`

How would I correctly query the DB so that I get the expected record?

```
    //record in the db

    "_id": "a137f2c46f4611ecd83e5a36bda66813b79f057c",
    "company_name": "test",
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2020-11-29T19:56:08.507Z"
    },
    "flagged": true,
    "crawling": false,
    "crawls": [{
        "$date": "2020-12-01T22:32:37.575Z"
    }, {
        "$date": "2020-12-01T22:38:43.826Z"
    }, {
        "$date": "2020-12-01T22:39:39.702Z"
    }, {
        "$date": "2020-12-05T22:32:37.575Z"
    }]


    //my query

    let res = await mongo.db('_businesses').collection('businesses').find(
        {
            crawls: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    $lte: '2020-11-25T00:00:00.000Z'
                }
            }
        }
    )

    //res = []
```

Comment: that probably needs a format. Did you try `$lte:{$toDate:"2020-11-25T00:00:00.000Z"}`

Comment: to be clear, `$date` is an object type, same than `$oid`, so they can't be compared with strings (well, you get false, null,...). hopefully will help you in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISODate. Eg:

```
"$lte" : ISODate("2020-11-25T00:00:00.000Z")
```